# Changing input in an EditText updates the wrong EditText inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I am going through a peculiar problem. I have multiple EditText inside a RelativeLayout which is ultimately inside a ScrollView. My problem is that whenever I edit the second(or third and so on) EditText, it loses focus to the first EditText inside the ScrollView and this first EditText gets the keyboard input.

Here goes the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/particularsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/particularsTextView"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="PARTICULARS"
                 android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                 android:textStyle="bold"

            />
            <View 
                android:id="@+id/bar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_below="@+id/particularsTextView"

            />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/particularsParentRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_below="@+id/bar1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        />
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="NAME"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"

                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nameEditText"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/passwordTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="PASSWORD"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passwordEditText"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/nameEditText"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passwordTextView"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/passwordEditText"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CONFIRM PASSWORD"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/confirmPasswordTextView"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/birthdayTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="BIRTHDAY"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/birthdayEditText"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/birthdayEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/birthdayTextView"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        />
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/genderTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="GENDER"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/birthdayTextView"
                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/contactDetailsTextView"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/genderTextView"
                 android:text="CONTACT DETAILS"
                 android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                 />   
                 <View 
                android:id="@+id/bar2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactDetailsTextView"     
                />


                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/contactNoTextView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contactNoEditText"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                     android:text="CONTACT NO."
                     android:textSize="12sp"
                     android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     />
                 <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/contactNoEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/bar2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        />

                 <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/emailAddressTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="EMAIL AD."
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailAddressEditText"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailAddressEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/contactNoEditText"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailAddressEditText2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddressTextView"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"                 
                    />


                     <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/countryTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="COUNTRY"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddressEditText2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"

                        android:textSize="12sp"

                    />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/termsCheckbox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/countryTextView" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/termsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/termsCheckbox"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/termsCheckbox"
                    android:text="I AGREE TO THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS STATED"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/termsCheckbox"

                />

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/signupButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/termsTextView"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/signup"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>      

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How to resolve this issue ?

**EDIT:**

I have attached a screenshot of my problem. I have entered "h" in the passwordEditText but nameEditText gets the value.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mTabHost.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {}

        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            mTabHost.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnTouchModeChangeListener(mTabHost);
        }
    });
```

Add this code in MainActivity.Java @setTabs() function after

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

this line.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to desired edit text after you make the change: ex.

```
    myEditText3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    myEditText3.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Hm, try changing the ids in your xml and code, just by adding 1 for ex on all editTexts.  I have sometimes experienced a weird bug in eclipse when working with relative layout, and a similar thing happens, even though the ids are ok, they act like i am selecting different fields even though its obvious that the code and xml are ok. Changing the ids to different names helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's Working in my device.
I don't know why it's not working in yours, I think in java code, there may be some error.
But you can try,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

add 3rd line to your "parentLayout"

Comment: tried this way before but it didnt work..By the way I didnt try in any physical device